# ElasticSearh RestHighLevelClient , how to add retry?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

My current code is:
How to add more than one retry here?
and what does setMaxRetryTimeoutMillis do?

```
  return new RestHighLevelClient(RestClient.builder(HttpHost.create(esEndPoint))
                .setHttpClientConfigCallback(hacb -> hacb.addInterceptorLast(interceptor))
                .setRequestConfigCallback(
                        new RestClientBuilder.RequestConfigCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public RequestConfig.Builder customizeRequestConfig(RequestConfig.Builder builder) {
                                return builder
                                        .setConnectTimeout((int) TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(CONNECT_TIMEOUT))
                                        .setSocketTimeout((int) TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(SOCKET_TIMEOUT));
                            }
                        }
                )

        );
```